# Class member is being changed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I'm making a dice of the Royal Game of Ur in C#. It needs 4 4-sided pyramids that have 2 out of 4 peaks colored white. This means that a single dice gives 50/50 chance of being either 0 or 1.

Now look at this code and tell me why it sometimes gives me 5 and 6.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public Button rollButton;
    public int result;

    void Start()
    {
        rollButton.onClick.AddListener(onClick);
    }

    void resultReset()
    {
        Debug.Log("Setting result from " + result + " to 0");
        result = 0;
    }

    public int Calculate()
    {        
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int num = Random.Range(0,2); // Either 1 or 0.

            result = result + num; // num is added to total result
            if (result > 4)
            {
                Debug.Log("Rolling " + result + " not possible!!");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    void onClick()
    {
        resultReset();

        int iRolled = Calculate();
        Debug.Log("I rolled " + iRolled); // Sometimes gives 5+ and skips the for loop (like, goes 1-2 times and gives out an impossible number)
    }

}
```

Comment: It is cleared in the onClick method using resultReset method to track what I rolled before and what it thinks it rolled

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52936632/edit) your question to include the output you're getting, as well as a screenshot showing how your button is configured in the Unity Inspector.

Comment: After `int num = Random.Range(0,2); // Either 1 or 0.` please add debug logging for the value of `num` and `result`. Then please update your question to include the (in your view) incorrect log entries you are receiving (i.e. show us how `result` changes over time to be > 4.

Comment: Before and after `int iRolled = Calculate();` please add similar logging for `result` and `iLogged` also. All of those logs combined should highlight if there is another caller to those methods.

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce this, but my best guess would be that the onClick method is tied to two different objects that are both being triggered simultaneously?  Or maybe the event handler is added to a single object multiple times somehow.  Either might explain why it is being fired twice.  You might have a race conditions where both objects reset the [shared] result and then both start adding to it at the same time.  Try running your loop against non-shared local variables instead, like this:

```
public int Calculate()
{
    int thisRoll = 0;       // only accessible from inside the method

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int num = Random.Range(0,2); // Either 1 or 0.

        thisRoll = thisRoll + num; // num is added to total result
        if (thisRoll > 4)
        {
            Debug.Log("Rolling " + thisRoll + " not possible!!");
        }
    }
    return thisRoll;
}

void onClick()
{
    //resultReset();        // not necessary anymore

    int iRolled = Calculate();
    Debug.Log("I rolled " + iRolled); // Sometimes gives 5+ and skips the for loop (like, goes 1-2 times and gives out an impossible number)

    // set result here if you actually need it in addition to iRolled:
    result = iRolled;
}
```

Comment: I, too, cannot reproduce this. To ensure that the result is resetting, add another log at the start of the `Calculate` method. You can also check the value of result per iteration inside the for loop. However, the safest way to ensure a fresh value per call to Calculate is to do what @Elemental Pete answered by making the each roll's result independent from every other spin.

Answer (score 0):

At least one of `OnClick` and `Calculate` is being called twice.

One time is accounted for by the call to `AddListener` when Unity calls `Start()` on `ButtonScript`.  Any additional calls on a click would create a race condition that could produce unexpected output.

Make sure that neither of those methods are included in the button's list of `On Click` events in the inspector before you run the scene.